# get string piece, before last needle

Tags: php, string, function

Given

```
 $str = "asd/fgh/jkl/123
```

If we want to get string piece after last slash , we can use function `strrchr()` right?
In php not function, to get string piece, before last slah, that is `asd/fgh/jkl` ?

I know this can make via regex or other way, I am asking about internal function?

Answer (score 24):

You can use

```
$str = "asd/fgh/jkl/123";
echo substr($str, 0,strrpos($str, '/'));
```

Output

```
asd/fgh/jkl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "asd/fgh/jkl/123";

$lastPiece = end(explode("/", $str));

echo $lastPiece;
```

output: 123;

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) converts the string into an array using "/" as a separator (you can pick the separator)

[end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) returns the last item of the array

Comment: If needed get piece after last shlash, there is function strrchr() for this, I am asking: not function, to get piece `before` last slash ?

Comment: I don't understand the "not function" part sorry, you mean not using an internal function from php? or not function at all?

Comment: works, but better put it as `$lastPiece =explode("/", $str)` and then use  
 `$lastPiece =end( $lastPiece )`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by:

`explode` — Split a string by string ([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php))

```
$pieces = explode("/", $str );
```

example

```
$str = "asd/fgh/jkl/123";
$pieces = explode("/", $str );
print_r($pieces);

$count= count($pieces);
echo $pieces[$count-1]; //or
echo  end($pieces);
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/sFTvYkcp)

Comment: That is, no  internal function in php, for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this powerful custom function

```
 /* $position = false and $sub = false show result of before first occurance of $needle */
 /* $position = true and $sub false show result of before last occurance of $needle     */
 /* $position = false and $sub = true show result of after first occurance of $needle   */  
 /* $position = true and $sub true show result of after last occurance of         $needle       */


function CustomStrStr($str,$needle,$position = false,$sub = false)
{
$Isneedle = strpos($str,$needle);
if ($Isneedle === false)
return false;

    $needlePos =0;
    $return;
    if ( $position === false )
        $needlePos = strpos($str,$needle);
    else
        $needlePos = strrpos($str,$needle);

    if ($sub === false)
        $return = substr($str,0,$needlePos);
    else
        $return = substr($str,$needlePos+strlen($needle));

return $return;         
}
```